# How do you end a python guess number game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i created a loop guess number game with help from @J DawG, but i couldn't figure out how to make it terminate if the user tells it to.  Here's my code:

```
import random

inplay = 0
x = ""
def in_play():
    global inplay, guessesTaken
    guessesTaken = 0
    if inplay == True:
        play()
    else:
        inplay = True
        play()

def play():
    global guessesTaken
    print('Hello! What is your name?')
    myName = input()

    number = random.randint(1, 20)
    print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

    while guessesTaken < 5:
        print('Take a guess.') 
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess) or str(guess)
        guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

        if guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low.') 

        elif guess > number:
            print('Your guess is too high.')

        elif guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + '   guesses!')
        in_play()

    elif guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
        in_play()


in_play()
```

So yeah, if you could please answer this relatively soon, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

change `while guessesTaken < 5:` to `while guessesTaken < 5 and not finishedPlaying:`. make `finishedPlaying = False` at the start and set it to `True` when you prompt the user to ask if he's done and he indicates he is.

By the way, do not do this:

`guess = int(guess) or str(guess)`

If `int(guess)` fails to work, then 1) it will throw an Exception, not return a false-like value, 2) you can't do anything anyway - if it's not a number it's not a valid guess 3) it was a string to begin with anyway.

The semantics of `or` in Python is: Evaluate my first operand. If it is a true-like value in a boolean context (does not turn into `False` if you do `bool(operand)` on it), return it. Else, evaluate my second operand and return it.

Answer (score -2):

you can end the script with:

```
import sys # put this at the top of the script
sys.exit() # when you want to end the script
```

You can, for example, let people type in "exit" in the input, check for that, and call exit when it happens.